# Robot overturn when I controlled with the keyboard

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just started with ROS and Gazebo and I'm learning how and where to implement my code to control a robot in Gazebo.

I'm trying to control robot Pioneer 2DX robot in Gazebo using ROS.

To do it, I have followed the tutorial: [Controlling a differential drive robot in Gazebo from ROS](http://machineawakening.blogspot.com/2015/05/controlling-differential-drive-robot-in.html). And to control it with the keyboard, I run this:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/pioneer2dxCamera/cmd_vel
```

But, there is a problem, because if I press up key, and then down key the robot overturn:

[image: image description]

I think, the problem is because the linear velocity changes from 2 to -2. Look:

```
linear: 
  x: 2.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: -2.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
```

I have decided to modify program `turtle_teleop_key` to store current linear and angular velocity, and, if linear velocity is 2 and I press down key, linear velocity will 0 instead of -2.

**My question is**:

**Is this the correct place to do it or do I have to do it in the diff drive plugin?**

By the way, I'm using this plugin, libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so, to control the robot.

Yes, I know that change linear velocity to 2 to -2 will flip a real robot too. I'm not asking that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306284/robot-overturn-when-i-controlled-with-the-keyboard/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-10-19**:
This is probably not too far from reality; commanding a change in velocity from 2m/s to -2m/s could probably flip the real robot too. Maybe choose a lower speed?

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-10-21**:
@ahendrix Yes, I know that is not real. I'm not asking that, I'm asking where that: in diff drive plugin or in program to control the robot with keyboard?

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-10-21**:
Ok. So, I will modify the program that controls the robot with the keyboard instead of modifying the diff drive plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're controlling it in exactly the right way, you're just using a speed that's too high. Try using 0.1ms^1 instead which is a more realistic speed for that platform. By changing instantly from +2 to -2 ms^1 you're asking the robot to instantly change it's velocity by 14.4 Kmph, no wonder it flips!

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0